# Can't display image from RSS/XML through templates in XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, rss

I am having trouble getting the image to display in the xml file that is setup in the stylesheet.

Here is the content of the XML file

```
      <image>
        <title>SciTimes.com</title>
        <link>home.htm</link>
        <url>scitimes.jpg</url>
        <width>620</width>
        <height>96</height>
        <description>SciTimes delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on the latest stories from the world of science and technology.
        </description>
      </image>
```

Then, where I am having the problem is in the XSL file.  I am having a problem displaying the image from the image element in the XML file above.

This is the portion I am strugling with.  I am attempting to display the scitimes.jpg image that is referenced in the XML file

Here I create the template for the image

```
        <xsl:template match="image" >
            <a href="{link}">
                <img src="{url}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}" longdesc="{descriptions}"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:template>
```

and then within the root template I apply it

```
                <div id="logo">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="channel/image"/>
                </div>
```

But is it not displaying

Comment: Based on your input above, please show us what is your expected output.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "disconnect" and what exactly do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I have everything except I am not able to get the image to show up that I have created a template for and then referenced in the root template.   I have updated the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the disconnect is context and in XSLT context is (almost) everything.

For example, the first template matches `/` and the first `xsl:value-of` is selecting `channel/title`. This won't match anything because the current context is `/`.

Try changing the match of the first template to `/rss` or `/*`. This should fill in *some* of the details. However, it looks like you are expecting the context to change when it hasn't. This appears to start in the second `div` with `id="links"` (for example when you try to get the value of `dc:subject`). The context is still `/`.

I would suggest using more of a "push" approach by using `xsl:apply-templates` more. Using one giant template and "pulling" data with `xsl:value-of` can get unmanageable pretty quickly.